# Parsing string returning from Python function in C

Tags: python, c++

I am using Python code within C++ code using C python apis and trying to parse the string returned from a function written in Python.

I am able to parse lists, dictionary but couldn't find out how to parse strings returning from python function. I tried one way but getting segmentation fault.
Any idea??
Here is my code

hell.py -

```
import json

### this is just sample code and I need to send back this
def get_json():
    
    res = '{"Hello": [2.3, 4.5, 7.8], "How": 0, "Why": "no"}' # sample dict needs to be sent back
    a = json.loads(res)
    print(a)

    l1 =  json.dumps(a)   # now l1 is the string

    return  l1  #since l1 is string now, I need to send back this
```

My c code -

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN

#include</usr/include/python3.6/Python.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

PyObject *mymodule = PyImport_ImportModule("hell");                         PyErr_Print();
PyObject *myfunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymodule, "get_json");          PyErr_Print();

PyObject *result1 = PyObject_CallObject(myfunc1, NULL);                     PyErr_Print();

char * buff = new char[100];
buff = PyByteArray_AsString(result1);

cout<<buff[0]<<endl; // getting segmentation fault here ..
```

Thanks
Akhi

Comment: `cout<<buff[0]<<endl;` is c++ and not c

Comment: And I can say for sure that `char * buff = new char[100];
buff = PyByteArray_AsString(result1);` does not do what you think

Comment: Also, never use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: Yeah, it's actually c++. I tried to send back bytes too  and then tried this char * buff = new char[100]; buff = PyByteArray_AsString(result1); Got segmentation fault

Comment: Yeah, Not using #include <bits/stdc++.h> . This code is just sample code.

Comment: You need to learn what pointers are. Your allocation `new char[100]` is completely pointless since the first thing you do is to reassign the pointer. That also causes a memory leak.

Comment: Pointers and other  things can be taken care. for sure.  Just want to make this string parsing work first.

Comment: One can dowvote it without giving the answer that has been asked. Thank anyway

Answer (score 1):

I got it-
We need to send bytes and receive in bytes.

c code -

```
void get_dict_as_string(){

    PyObject *mymodule = PyImport_ImportModule("hell");                         PyErr_Print();
    PyObject *myfunc1 = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymodule, "get_json");           PyErr_Print();

    PyObject *result1 = PyObject_CallObject(myfunc1, NULL);                     PyErr_Print();

    Py_ssize_t s = PyByteArray_Check(result1);
    cout<<"check bytes: "<<s<<endl;

    char * buff_py = PyByteArray_AsString(result1);
    long byte_size = PyByteArray_Size(result1);
    cout<<"byte size : "<<byte_size<<endl;

    for(int i =0; i<byte_size; i++){

        char retval = buff_py[i]; 
        printf("%c ", retval);

    }
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Python code -

```
def get_json():
    
    res = '{"Hello": [2.3, 4.5, 7.8], "How": 0, "Why": "no", "check": [2.3, 9.0567, 1.345]}'

    a = json.loads(res)
    l1 =  json.dumps(a)

    e = l1.encode('utf-8')

    return bytearray(e)
```

Comment: It's still C++. I have changed the tags. Nice that you found the answer though.

Comment: Actually, I am using both c and c++. SInce I am more of a C person, here other things are in c++ so I combined them both while still using g++ compiler so that works very well.

Comment: Tags should be about what the question is about, not your personality ;)

Comment: But if you go and see the documentation of c python, it is c apis, not c++ and that's what the tag was. 

Comment: Yep, but the code you had problem with is C++. For details I refer to this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360709/6699433

Comment: I had the problem finding exact implementation of parsing from c-python apis for which I could not find any examples. So I thought if anyone here had worked on that part can provide me exact implementation or some example. I was not asking c++ code here. Sorry if I could not explain my question. I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thanks

Comment: It's pretty simple. If you want help with C code, then post C code in your question.